# Mudar a cor do values

Tags: php, html, css

Possuo um `<form>` no qual eu retorno informações que consultei no bd, até ai tudo está funcionando perfeitamente, porém eu gostaria de mudar a cor da `value` de acordo com o resultado. Se o `value` for "PENDENTE" deve ficar vermelho e se o `value` for "APROVADO" ficar verde.

Abaixo segue o trecho de código.

```html
<form>
  <label id="label">
     Status
  </label>
  <input id="input" type="text" class="form-control" name="status" 
     value="<?php echo " $status " ?>" 
     placeholder="" style="text-transform:uppercase" disabled="disabled">
</form>
```

Agradeço.

Comment: Você quer mudar a cor do texto dentro do input?

Comment: Bem-vindo Gabriel Barreto, faça um tour https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PHP**

```
<?php

if($status=="PENDENTE"){
    $cor="red";
}else{
    $cor="green";
}
?>
```

**HTML**
Adicione no input `style="background-color : <?php echo $cor ?>;"`

```
<form>
  <label id="label">Status</label>
  <input id="input" type="text" class="form-control" style="background-color : <?php echo $cor ?>;" name="status" value="<?php echo " $status " ?>" placeholder="" style="text-transform:uppercase" disabled="disabled">
</form>
```

Comment: Desculpa a demora para responder, mas ajudou muito. Obrigado Leo!!!

Answer (score 0):

Algo como o exemplo abaixo deve alterar a cor do texto:

```
<style>
.pendente
{
    input, select, textarea{
        color: #ff0000;
    }
}
</style>

<form>
  <label id="label">Status</label>
  <input id="input" type="text" class="form-control <?php if(strtoupper($status) === 'PENDENTE') { echo 'pendente'; } ?>" name="status" value="<?php echo " $status " ?>" placeholder="" style="text-transform:uppercase" disabled="disabled">
</form>
```